Lipschitz bounds and homotopy groups of diffeomorphism groups
Let $M$ denote a closed Riemannian manifold. Let $\mathrm{Diff}_0^L(M)$ denote the supspace of the identity component of the diffeomorphism group $\mathrm{Diff}_0(M)$ of diffeomorphisms with Lipschitz constant at most $L$. Since $M$ is closed we have
$$
\mathrm{Diff}_0(M) = \bigcup_L \mathrm{Diff}_0^L(M)
$$
Does there exist an $L$ such that the inclusion
$
\mathrm{Diff}_0^L(M) \to \mathrm{Diff}_0(M)
$
is surjective on all higher homotopy groups? A little weaker, for a given $k$, does there exist an $L$ such that $\mathrm{Diff}_0^L(M) \to \mathrm{Diff}_0(M)$ is surjective on the $k$-th homotopy group?
If the answer to any of these questions is yes, what happens for the whole diffeomorphism group?
If the homotopy groups are finitely generated, then the answer to the second question is evidently "yes". I think this occurs sometimes if $M$ is simply-connected. I'm mostly interested in the case where $M$ has non-zero fundamental group.

If either statement is true for one component then it's true for other components where the $L$ you need to take depends on the component, by just picking any diffeomorphism in one component, composing every diffeomorphism in the identity component with Lipshchitz constant at most $L$ with it, and using that Lipshchitz constants multiply under composition. On the other hand, it is often clear that the $L$ one must take depends on the component even to have a single diffeomorphism in the component with Lipschitz constant at most $L$, e.g. for a torus.

I believe the answer is no, at least for the manifold $M = S^1 \times D^{m-1}$, when $m \geq 4$.   At present I know it to fail for $k=0$ and $k=m-4$, but it likely fails for a broad range of values of $k$.   This is using diffeomorphisms that are the identity on the boundary.  Similar results hold for $Diff(S^1 \times S^{m-1})$.
The basic idea is the invariant of these homotopy groups $\pi_0 Diff(S^1 \times D^{m-1})$ and $\pi_{m-4} Diff(S^1 \times D^{m-1})$ is a type of equivariant linking invariant, i.e. we think of the diffeomorphism group as acting on the configuration space of two or three points in $S^1 \times D^{m-1}$ and then lift that to an action on the universal cover of that configuration space.  The invariant is (essentially) defined on that covering space of the configuration space. Technically you need a compactification of the configuration space, but let's suppress the details for now.
A Lipschitz bound with Lipschitz constant $\alpha$ would tell you that the Laurent polynomial invariants (we call them the $W_2$ and $W_3$-invariants) would have bounded polynomial degree, a fixed multiple of $\alpha$.   The problem is one can obtain invariants with arbitrary large polynomial degree.   These results appear in a few papers:

https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.05010
https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.09029
https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.09545

The last paper by Watanabe uses a different invariant, i.e. $W_2$ and $W_3$ appear only in references (1) and (2).
I think all you can hope for is a filtration of the homotopy groups by Lipschitz constants.
But perhaps for manifolds in large dimensions $m \geq 5$ and finite fundamental group you could hope for such a theorem.    I suppose for a broad range of such homotopy groups you could deduce existence of the Lipschitz constants from results on the finiteness of $\pi_k Diff(M)$.  This paper of Bustamante, Krannich and Kupers gives some results: https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.13468
It would be interesting if the best-possible Lipschitz constants were directly related to the order of the homotopy-group, or if there is something more interesting and subtle going on.

It probably fails for $M=$ the 2-torus, considering a loop of isotopies $f=(f_t)$ that fix a basepoint $a$ and whose differentials at $a$ are the rotations of angle $2\pi t$. Consider for every $n$ the $n$th power $f^n$ of this loop in $\pi_1(Diff(M)_0)$. Any loop $g_t$ in $\pi_1(Diff(M)_0)$ homotopic to $f^n$ can be made to fix $a$ by composing them with isometries which do not change their Lipschitz constants.

@GaelMeigniez: I'm not seeing his this is related to the question.  Isn't the Lipschitz constant for your loop just $L=1$?
